# For yield with Rep[Optional[...]] using Slick

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, slick

I'm trying to check if my column contains at least one element from provided List with following pseudocode:

Where b.testColumn = **Rep[Optional[List]]**.

```
def checkTest(id: UUID, input: List[String]) = {

  for {
    a <- a.query if a.id === id
    b <- b.query if a.bId === b.id && b.testColumn.intersect(input)
  } yield b

  ApplicationDatabase.slick.run...
}
```

And I'm getting an error with type mismatch for following code:

```
b <- b.query if a.bId === b.id && b.testColumn.intersect(input)
```

My question is - how I can easily unwrap **Rep[Optional[...]]** and compare with my input values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an investigation, the easiest way to access `Rep[Optional[...]]` that I found is by doing `.map`

e.g. - `b <- b.query if a.bId === b.id && b.map(_.testColumn).inSetBind(input)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [inSet](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html#id21)?

`b <- b.query if a.bId === b.id && b.testColumn.inSet(input)`

Comment: Yessir, just to clarify testColumn type is column[Option[List[String]]]

Comment: You can use it with Option.